# Why isn't $< \{ 1\} \{2 \}>$ contained in $< \{1,2\} \{3,4\}>$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why isn't subsequence $< \{ 1\} \{2 \}>$ contained in sequence $< \{1,2\} \{3,4\}>$?

Since: $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$ and $\{2\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$?

Is it because they belong to the same set (that's, they index into the same set) that $<\{ 1\} \{2 \}>$ isn't a subsequence of the given sequence?

Comparatively,

$$<\{2\} \{4\}>$$ is contained in

$$<\{2,4\}\{2,4\}\{2,5\}>$$

---

A sequence $<a_1...a_n>$ is contained in $<b_1,...,b_m>$ if exists integers $i_1 < ... < i_n$ such that $a_1 \subseteq b_{i1}, ..., a_n \subseteq b_{in}$.

Comment: What does that notation even mean? It doesn't appear to be standard.

Comment: Does the notation $\langle \{1,2\}\{3,4\}\rangle$ stand for a sequence of length two with first term equal to the set $\{1,2\}$ and second term equal to the set $\{3,4\}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Exactly.

Comment: Why would $\{1\} \subset \{1,2\} \in \{\{1,2\}\{3,4\}\}$ make you think $\{1\}\} \in \{1,2\}$?   "avec" is in "french" and "french" is in "european languages" but "avec" is not in"european languages".  It literally is not different than that.  $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ are in the sequence and they are the only things that are.  The elements *within* $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ are not in the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A sequence $<a_1...a_n>$ is contained in $<b_1,...,b_m>$ if exists integers $i_1<...<i_n$ such that $a_1⊆b_{i_1},...,a_{n}⊆b_{i_n}$.

That answers your question doesn't it?

$b_1 = \{1\}\subset a_1$ but $b_2 = \{2\} \subset a_1$.  And $1 = 1$.  It is not the case that $1 < 1$.

...

So by your definition, $<\{1\},\{3\}>$ is contained.

.....

I must say I have *NEVER* heard of your definition of a sequence of subsets being "contained" in a sequence of sets.  And I must say I don't like it.  It is way too ambiguous and sounds too much like being a subsequence--  which  it is nothing of the sort.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was asking about.